# Swift Delegate (contactDelegate) explanation

Tags: swift, delegates

I've research a lot on what delegate means but somehow my understand doesn't fit with this explanation. This is from a tutorial:

```
    physicsWorld.contactDelegate = self
```

and this is his explanation: "This sets up the physics world to have no gravity, and **sets the scene as the delegate to be notified when two physics bodies collide.**"

I thought delegate is just a class that uses a protocol. Does anyone have a different explanation for this? what exactly is that line do? Thanks.
(ignore the gravity part, there's another line of code)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the Swift documentation for the [PhysicsWorld class](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKPhysicsWorld_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/SKPhysicsWorld/contactDelegate):

> **contactDelegate  Property**
>
> A delegate that is called when two physics bodies come in contact with
>   each other.

Therefore when we see the line:

```
physicsWorld.contactDelegate = self
```

We are setting the contactDelegate property on the physicsWorld instance so that when two physics objects collide some method will be called i.e. the delegate.

By assigning `self` we are delegating the responsibility of responding to physics object collisions to the class (GameScene).

```
override func didMoveToView(view: SKView)
```

Because we are overriding this method in the GameScene class which inherits from the SKScene class we are essentially saying:

"Don't use SKScene `didMoveToView()` use this GameScene version of `didMoveToView()`" (because self refers to the GameScene class).

> So the function "didBeginContact()" is a delegate? and contactDelegate always has to be the class that's going to implement the "didBeginContact()" function (or any other function from the delegate protocol)?

I assume that the didBeginContact() method calls the method that is set to the contactDelegate property.

Java does not have delegates. A delegate is like a variable except it stores a method. You can use the variable to then call the method. (If you know some C it is a pointer to a function)

[This](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/orm-9780596521066-01-17.aspx) helped me understand delegates when I first came across them.

Comment: I guess it's this word delegate that's getting to me. I really hate Swift's naming convention, especially for methods. So the function "didBeginContact()" is a delegate? and contactDelegate always has to be the class that's going to implement the "didBeginContact()" function (or any other function from the delegate protocol)? and lastly, is there an equivalent word for delegate in java or any C family languages?

Answer (score 0):

A delegate **is** a protocol, also sometimes called a "delegate protocol". The class containing the quoted line of code *becomes the delegate* and gets the messages of the *protocol* in question. The `physicsWorld` will contact its delegate to inform it of a collision. If the delegate methods are implemented (i.e. the controller *conforms* to the delegate protocol), it can take appropriate action when it is notified.

Clear?